SQL collation of a new server
I have a new server (Windows 2022) and I need to install SQL Server 2022 with the collation to be Latin1_General_CI_AS, but in the setup there is no option to allow this, see the screenshot.
How can I set the collation in SQL to Latin1_General_CI_AS when I am forced to accept Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS?
SQL Server Install Collation Options:

I have insured the locale and timezone on the server is correct (UK) compared server install to another identical server which has as default Latin1_General_CI_AS like I need
Checked the server default codepage (437)

Do you need to set the server collation? What's wrong with per-database collation?

BTW, consider using the newer Latin1_100... collations. The non-_100 version is older and will handles some text differently to how users might expect.

SQL is a language specified by ISO/ANSI, and implemented by dozens, of which MS SQL Server is just one.

You should be able to do it by using the collation designer i think. Latin1_General_CI_AS is still available in 2022 at least. But why do you want same collation? are you doing some cross server joins?

Re: UK timezone - that shouldn't matter because you should be using UTC.


but in the setup there is no option to allow this, see the screenshot

Your screenshot shows the list of deprecated, legacy, ancient, "SQL collations". Do not use these (and Microsoft should stop making these the defaults today, as it contradicts their own documentation).
The Latin1_General_CI_AS collation can be selected by first selecting the top radio-button for "Windows collation designator and sort-order".


For Latin1_General_CI_AS you'll want:

Collation designator: Latin1_General.
Case-sensitive unchecked (CI = Case-insensitive)
Accent-sensitive: checked (AS = Accent-sensitive)

Leave all other options unchecked.

However, as it's 2024 now, consider using a less-antiquated collation, and take advantage of UTF-8 support while you're at it, so consider using Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8:

Collation designator: Latin1_General_100.
Case-sensitive unchecked (CI = Case-insensitive)
Accent-sensitive: checked (AS = Accent-sensitive)
Supplementary characters: checked (Needed for UTF-8 support)
Storage option: UTF-8

Leave all other options unchecked.

I agree with the first part, but utf8 collation is not an automatically good choice

@siggemannen Right, though as the OP said they're in the UK, I think it makes sense - unless they're hosting a database of Chinese literature...

There was some site that listed so many gotchas with utf8 (or actually sql server implementation of collations), which put me off it at least. The utf8 as in the encoding is indeed good choice!
